# Rails EXCEPT query (filter out records present in a joint table)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, associations

I'm trying to list the model instances that do not have the association with another model created yet.

Here is how my models are related:

Ticket.rb:

```
has_one :purchase
has_one :user, through: :purchase
```

User.rb:

```
has_many :purchases
has_many :tickets, through: :purchases
```

Purchase.rb:

```
belongs_to :ticket
belongs_to :user
```

I have an SQL query but have troubles when translating it to rails:

```
SELECT id FROM tickets
EXCEPT
SELECT ticket_id FROM purchases;
```

It works great as it returns all ids of the tickets that are not purchased yet.

I've tried this:

```
Ticket.joins('LEFT JOIN ON tickets.id = purchases.ticket_id').where(purchases: {ticket_id: nil})
```

but it seems not to be the right direction.

Comment: `Ticket.joins('LEFT JOIN ON tickets.id = purchases.ticket_id').where(purchases: {ticket_id: nil}` you forgot to specify the table name e.g. `Ticket.joins('LEFT JOIN purchases ON tickets.id = purchases.ticket_id').where(purchases: {ticket_id: nil}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to get the list of `Ticket` records with no associated purchases, use `.includes` instead. In my experience a `join` will fail with no associated records, and this will keep you from needing to write any actual SQL.

`Ticket.includes(:purchase).where(purchases: { ticket_id: nil} )`

The generated SQL query is a bit more difficult to read as a human, but I've used it several times and not seen any real difference in performance.

Comment: Did not notice at first that your Ticket model has a `has_one` relationship with purchase. For a `has_one` the include needs to use singular, but the where uses plural. Fixed this in the answer just now.